Can I use clamp rings and PEX-B fittings on Pex-A tubing?
My house has PEX-A tubing with a mix of expansion ring and sharkbite fittings. Multiple sharkbites have leaked, and having them replaced by a plumber is very expensive so I'm looking to do the rest myself.
I understand that expansion rings on PEX-A fittings would be best, but the tools to apply them cost hundreds of dollars, and I already have experience and tools for working with PEX-B clamp rings.
Is it appreciably worse to use clamp rings on PEX-A tubing? And if not, should I use PEX-B fittings to match the rings, or PEX-A fittings to match the tubing? Or should I bite the bullet, buy the dang PEX-A expansion ring tool, and do it right?

Have you checked if the tools are available as a rental?

Probably.
Check with the manufacturer of your PEX to be certain. Nobody is willing to state a blanket compatibility of PEX-A tubing with PEX-B fittings, but at least one individual manufacturer says it's an OK combination. The Apollo PEX FAQ page says:

Apollo PEX-A (Expansion PEX) pipe can be used with Apollo PEX-A or Apollo PEX-B fittings, brass and poly alloy. Apollo PEX-B pipe cannot be used with PEX-A fittings.

That said, PEX-A has better flow when used with expansion fittings or Sharkbites than it does with PEX-B, so if you have any fixtures with high water demands, you may find the use of PEX-B fittings unacceptable.
